# Validating date with Spring Boot or Hibernate Validator

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I've built a REST Service using Spring Boot. I'm also using Hibernate Validator to validate data. I have a REST endpoint like this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "${apiVersion.v_1}" + "/parameter-dates")
    public ResponseEntity createParameterDate( @RequestBody ParameterDate parameterDate){
// Some code that use parameterDate
}
```

`ParameterDate` is defined in a class like this:

```
public class ParameterDate {

    @NotNull(message = "Parameter Date Unadjusted can not be blank or null")
    private Date parameterDateUnadjusted;
    @NotNull(message = "Parameter Date Adjusted can not be blank or null")
    private Date parameterDateAdjusted;
    private Date parameterDateAdded;
    private Date parameterDateChanged;    
}
```

I would like to validate `parameterDateUnadjusted` and `parameterDateAdjusted` to make sure both of them are valid dates. I've tried with `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")` but it won't give me a validation error for not validate as long as they stick to `yyyy-MM-dd`. One example would be `2017-01-40` that it just interpret as `2017-02-09`. I guess `@DateTimeFormat` is rather a formatter than a validator. I also tried using Hibernate Validator's `@Pattern` and `rexexp` like `@Pattern(regexp="\\t(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\\d\\d\\t")`. But this gives me the error

`V000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Pattern' validating type 'java.util.Date'. Check configuration for 'parameterDateAdjusted'`

Any suggestion how I can validate these dates?

Comment: I think the REST service validation is the one to use.  By the time you get to Hibernate the data should be validated.

Comment: @duffymo Thanks. How would I implement that?

Comment: Take a peek at setting lenient to false:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606387/what-is-the-use-of-lenient

@du

Comment: @hooknc how do I sett lenient to false when using the annotation `@DateTimeFormat`?

Comment: Well, that is a good question.  I accidentally hit 'add comment' before I was ready and couldn't go back and edit my comment the way I wanted to.

From my, quick research, there doesn't seem to be able to set the lenient value on the hibernate's @DateTimeFormat.  However, you could implement your own validator fairly simply:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539724/validating-date-bean-validation-annotation-with-a-specific-format

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example to implement validator for Date object:

```
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = MyDateValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface ValidDate {

    String message() default "some message here";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}

public class MyDateValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidDate, Date> {
   public void initialize(ValidDate constraint) {
   }

   public boolean isValid(Date value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
      // validate the value here.
   }
}
```